# Uploading file is getting stuck - Deployed Django app using Nginx and gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos, gunicorn

I have deployed my django app on centos 7 using nginx and gunicorn, when I am trying to upload big file(25MB), it is getting hang after 80-90% upload, I went through many solutions and changed my nginx.conf file accordingly but nothing worked.
I am not getting any error or logs regarding same in my nginx log file, Client is not getting any response back from server.

I am not getting whats going wrong, please help me in this.

**- gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=prod
Group=nginx

WorkingDirectory=/home/prod/myProject1.0/myProject
ExecStart=/home/prod/myProjectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/prod/myProject1.0/myProject/myProject.sock myProject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**- nginx.conf**

```
user prod;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  _;


        client_body_in_file_only clean;


        client_max_body_size 8000M;
        client_body_buffer_size 80k;
        client_body_timeout 300s;
        client_body_temp_path /home/prod/media;
        send_timeout 300s;


        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /home/prod/myProject1.0/myProject/static/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/prod/myProject1.0/myProject/myProject.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

**My project folder structure -**

```
drwxrwxr-x. 4 prod prod        55 Nov 13 12:37 myProject1.0
drwxrwxr-x. 5 prod prod        56 Nov 13 13:12 myProjectenv
drwx------. 2 prod nginx        6 Nov 26 15:18 media
-rw-rw-r--. 1 prod prod       944 Nov 14 13:57 mynginx.pp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 prod prod       223 Nov 14 13:57 mynginx.te
-rw-rw-r--. 1 prod prod     30388 Oct  4 07:31 mysql80-community-release-el8.rpm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 prod prod  20753760 Mar 18  2019 Python-3.5.7.tgz
drwxrwxr-x. 2 prod prod       107 Nov 11 18:57 rpm
```